# GIT: merging files after working in wrong directories

Tags: wordpress, git, merge

I have a problem, I was working with a friend the first time on a Wordpress Theme and Git. It wasn't my first time using git and I assumed we have both installed and setup everything correctly.

However the problem is the following.

I have git installed in the `/wp-contents/themes` directory. My friend has git installed inside `/wp-contents/themes/theme-name`.

I worked on some files today, and so did he. However after a while of work and committing and pushing I finally see, that in our Repo there is now a directory `/wp-contents/themes/theme-name/themen-name` that I pushed and worked on somehow.

And the files he pushed are outside of the `/theme-name` folder for me. So on my local machine I see this now:

[image]

Meaning the files of my friend are visible for me outside of the actual theme.

However I worked inside the theme file on some files that should have been merged.

---

Long story short: How do I fix this and merge the files. What do I have todo to have the same working environment on both machines of me and my friend. Is there a way to merge those files and just have one theme-folder (without a copy inside it) and both working in the same folder.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree on which level you have the git repository, then one of you moves the files from one location to the other, reviews the changes with `git diff` and combines them properly, then go on from there. The one who has to switch his location of repository should then just re-clone the repo in the correct place.

Comment: But the changes have to be done manuay again, right. There is no way to merge the directories

Comment: Well, you could maybe extract the commits of one style with `git format-patch` and then apply them to the other style by changing the paths in the generated patch files before applying them with `git am`. That could be what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

```
git fetch /wp-contents/themes master
git merge -s ours --no-commit FETCH_HEAD
git read-tree --prefix=wp-contents/themes -u FETCH_HEAD
git commit -m "message"
```

Actually i propose to merge directories manually and commit the changes.